# Magento 2.4.4 Backoffice admin cannot save configuration

Tags: bug, magento2.4.4

Mozilla Firefox and Chrome seem to differ. Chrome works sometimes but Mozilla seem to not allow me to click the save button on a configuration change in the store admin configuration.

Truly annoying bug in admin configuration.

Comment: There must be some Required field is empty which isn't allowing you to click on Save Button , You need to open all the tabs and check if any required field is missing.

Comment: its better to attach screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix to the issue. Manually applying the patch located at https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/26b484075a60b4a384ae1f43aa5cf3ff1fb1d8fa fixes the issue.